# Problems using a nodeJS server with a ReactJS front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server

my first post here and I have a project in university where I have to make a website using reactJS for the interface and nodeJS for the server.

The problem is that I've read a lot of tutorials and can't seem to make it work:

Ive followed tutorials and used Express and I could set up a server (on local host 8080 for example, then writing some html code in the page) but then I can't display the pages I want on my react project. I'm really struggling to understand how to do this, as the tutorials i've read only allow me to show the html pages. do I have to integrate the reactJS code into the html files?

Sorry for bad english btw

heres the repository : https://github.com/NGYMich/miloscollection

here's the errors I get when I try to use express :

×
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
C:/Users/CRYSTA/projet_l3ad2/node_modules/express/lib/request.js:31
  28 |  * @public
  29 |  */
  30 |

> 31 | var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype)
>     32 | 
>     33 | /**
>     34 |  * Module exports.

Comment: hey welcome to stack. you need to be more specific, like showing error messages, expected results, unexpected results etc. have you tried https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app for your front end?

Comment: thanks! well we've already started the project, should I just go back and make a new repository for the project? my teacher told me to clean up the repository so I don't really know which files I can / should delete if I use your link (ive edited my original post to link my folder)

Comment: no, use the create-react-app command line utility to scaffold a new project and use that as a guide to understand how a basic react application should work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Express, and that you've packaged your React code using something like webpack into a bundle, you simply need to serve an HTML page with the bundle on any request to the backend that isn't matched by an API route. So, essentially all you'll need is:

```
const app = express();

// declare other API routes...

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Where `index.html` is an HTML file pointing to your bundle. If you aren't familiar with webpack, check out Facebook's [Create React App](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) for an example of a full pipeline.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
yes this works, but I'm being really dumb here, how do I put the reactJS components into html?

heres my repository btw, just edited my post https://github.com/NGYMich/miloscollection

Comment: You need to include a script tag in your html pointing to your bundle. So at the end of the `body` tag, you would put something like `<script src="/path/to/my/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks I figured out.. but I can't seem to find how to display my react components after including the script tag..
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

  <h1> Hello everyone

<script src="Main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
`
looks like this